# Apache Camel | Spring Testing | Intercept Route is not working

Tags: java, junit, apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-test

I am new to apache camel so I am still struggling to write camel test cases.

I have below route defined

```
from("direct:routeToTest")
        .id(ROUTE_ID)
        .to(LOOK_UP_ROUTE)
        .choice()
           .when(some-condition)        
             .choice()
                .when(condition)
                .to(CREATE_ROUTE)
               .otherwise().process(exchange -> exchange.getIn().setBody(prepareResponse(""))
             .endChoice()
          .otherwise()
            .log("Some Issue")
            .process(exchange -> unknownError(exchange))
        .endChoice();
  }
```

while testing I am trying to intercept **to** defined in my route and set some mock response to it. So after some search I found using **adviceWith** is the right way to achieve it.

So my test is like below. The outcome of the test is, it is still going to Look_up_route (direct:lookUpRoute, another route defined) for processing with the data passed but the expectation is code should skip this to and set response as "MockResponse"

```
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@UseAdviceWith
@MockEndpoints
@DisableJmx(false)
public class RouteTest {

  @Autowired
  private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

  @Autowired
  private CamelContext context;

 @Test
  public void testResponseToJSON() throws Exception {
    SomeObject someObject = getObject();
    context.getRouteDefinition(ROUTE_ID).adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
          @Override
          public void configure() throws Exception {
            interceptSendToEndpoint(LOOK_UP_ROUTE)
                .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
                .transform("MockOutput");
        }
    );
    context.start();
    Object object = producerTemplate.requestBody(direct:routeToTest, someObject);
  }

}
```

I'd like to know how do I skip .to(LOOK_UP_ROUTE) and set mockResponse to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your [intercept](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/intercept.html) statement looks good at first sight. However, have a look at this answer for an alternative approach.

You have to

1. Add an `id` to the LOOK_UP_ROUTE step in your route
2. Then you can use [adviceWith](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CAMEL/AdviceWith) to remove or manipulate the marked step in your tests
3. Set the message body (and header) to whatever it should be for your test